# Using XPath to extract XOM elements from documents with unnecessary namespaces

Tags: xpath, xml-namespaces, xom

I'm trying to parse some HTML returned by an external system with XOM. The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<body>
  <div>
    Help I am trapped in a fortune cookie factory
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Actually it's significantly messier, but it has this DOCTYPE declaration and these namespace and language declarations, and the HTML above exhibits the same problem as the real HTML.)

What I want to do is extract the content of the `<div>`, but the namespace declaration seems to be confusing XPath. If I strip out the namespace declaration (by hand, from the file), the following code finds the `<div>`, no problem:

```
Document document = ...
Nodes divs = document.query("//div");
```

But with the namespace, the returned `Nodes` has a size of 0.

All right, how about if I strip the namespace programmatically?

```
Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
rootElement.removeNamespaceDeclaration(rootElement.getNamespacePrefix());
```

...looks like it should work, but does nothing. From the [javadoc](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Element.html#removeNamespaceDeclaration(java.lang.String)):

> This method only removes additional namespaces added with `addNamespaceDeclaration.`

Okay, I thought, I'll provide the namespace to the query:

```
XPathContext context = 
    XPathContext.makeNamespaceContext(document.getRootElement());
Nodes divs = document.query("//div", context);
```

Size still zero.

How about constructing the namespace context by hand?

```
XPathContext context = context = new XPathContext(
     rootElement.getNamespacePrefix(), rootElement.getNamespaceURI());
Nodes divs = document.query("//div", context);
```

The `XPathContext` constructor blows up with:

```
nu.xom.NamespaceConflictException: 
    XPath expressions do not use the default namespace
```

So, I'm looking for either:

1. a way to make this query work, or
2. a way to programmatically strip the namespace declarations, or
3. an explanation of the correct approach, assuming both of these are wrong.

---

**Update:** Based on [Lev Levitsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9674145/27358) and the [Jaxen FAQ](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/faq.html) I came up with the following hack:

```
XPathContext context = new XPathContext(
    "foo", 
    document.getRootElement().getNamespaceURI());
Nodes divs = document.query("//foo:div");
```

This still seems a bit demented to me, but I guess it's the way Jaxen wants you to do things.

---

**Update #2:** As noted below and [all over the Internet](http://www.google.com/search?q="default+namespace"+xpath), this isn't Jaxen's fault; it's just XPath being XPath.

So, while this hack works, I would still like a way to strip the namespace declaration. Preferably without going as far as XSLT.

Comment: This is the way XPath works with namespaces, it does not depend on Jaxen: if you want to match something with a namespace you must use an explicit prefix in the XPath

Comment: Yes, on further reading I see that. So, okay, no blame attaches to Jaxen, but it still seems a bit demented. Or, at best, pedantic, and designed primarily for maximum correctness in unrealistic use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either specify the namespace directly with something like

```
Nodes divs = document.query("//{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div");
```

or using prefixes that are mapped to respective namespaces (I guess that is what `NamespaceContext` is for, but there are no prefixes in your query).

*Unfortunately, I don't know how it's implemented in Java, but I can provide a Python example if it helps.*

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
Nodes divs = document.query("//*[local-name()='div' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']");
```